# Real numbers x, y are randomly chosen from the interval [0, 1]. Are the probability that 3x + y ≤ 1 and the probability that 3x + y < 1 equal?

Tags: probability, inequality

Real numbers **x**, **y** are randomly chosen from the interval **[0, 1]**. Is the probability that $3x + y ≤ 1$ equal to the probability that $3x+y<1$? (*Because in the graph of the first case the inequality line is also considered, as it has $≤$ and we know considering a line doesn't add to the area. But in general sense, we're having points like $(x,y)=(0.2,0.4),(0.1,0.7)$ etc. adding to our probability whereas in the second case we don't.*)

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with continuous random variables. Events like $x=0.2,y=0.8$ have proabiblity $0$. A precise argument for $P(3x+y \leq 1)=P(3x+y <1)$ follows from the measure theoretic fact that $P(3x+y = 1)=0$ because the two dimensional Lebesgue measure of a stright line segement is $0$. [Intutively, the area of the line segment is $0$].